# Xcode - The best way to setup global content to be used in multiple view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hoi, I'm working with Objective C on a project in Xcode, and I've got a couple view controllers going..

Now I'm trying to set up some global content that is displayed in all the view controllers (a simple header with a logo and some text, and a simple footer with info about the app version and some stuff like that).

So what I'm wondering is; what is the best practice for creating some uiviews and uilabels that is displayed in all the view controllers?

Comment: Create a subclass of `UIViewController` add "some stuff" as you said. And extend all view controllers with this subclass.

Comment: It seems there are many ways to go about doing this and really no "standard" or a "correct" way recommended by apple or something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also create a global view controller that display an other view controller through a ContainerView, plus the additional content you want on every controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems like the best and most organized solution

Answer (score 1):

Create custom view classes for header and footer with xib file that contains custom properties that you need. Init and add these views where you want.